# Change the flow layout of a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Based on filter results, I need to change the flow layout of a collection view and reload the data using a different kind of cell. However you can't just do this:

```
myCollectionView.flowLayout = ...
```

So how is it possible to change the flow layout of a collection view?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**SHORT AND SIMPLE ANSWER**

You can access/set the flowLayout like this:

```
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = ...
```

**LONG ANSWER**

You said:

> However you can't just do this:
>
> ```
> myCollectionView.flowLayout = ...
> ```

But in fact you can set the collection view’s [`collectionViewLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618047-collectionviewlayout), and it does just what you want:

> Assigning a new layout object to this property causes the new layout to be applied ... to the collection view’s items.

Comment: And it's extremely cool - when you set the layout, you should see animation as the cells are repositioned.

Comment: The flowLayout property has changed name to collectionViewLayout.

Comment: @ShuZhang You have not understood the question and answer. The question is why there is no `flowLayout` property. The answer is that there is a `collectionViewLayout` property instead.

Comment: @pavan you have not understood the answer. Read the comments. The OP is the one who said `flowLayout`. I am just quoting him (that is what the yellow block means). My _answer_, starting with the word "actually", points him to `collectionViewLayout`.

Comment: If you use a UICollectionViewController, the collectionViewLayout property is readOnly.  That is you cannot set it via: self.collectionViewLayout = myFlowLayout  One has to actually get down to the collectionView and set it like: self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = myFlowLayout

Comment: @anorskdev That is actually what my answer suggests. However, the link got broken over the years (Apple changed the format of its documentation). Updated the link to point to that property once again.